# Indicate to Go TCP Server that Java TCP Client Has Finished Writing to the Stream

Tags: java, go, tcp, client-server, eof

I'm writing a Java TCP Client that connects to a Golang TCP Server.

The server uses the below code to read messages from clients:

```
func (tcpHandler TCPHandler) getClientMsgBytes(connection *net.TCPConn) ([]byte, error) {
    clientMsgBytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(connection)
    if err != nil {            
        return nil, err
    }       

    return clientMsgBytes, nil
}
```

My client uses the below code to send messages to the server:

```
try (Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 9000)) {
    byte[] message = getMessage();

    DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

    outputStream.write(commandMessage);     

    // Read message from the sever...          
}
```

My problem is that the server keeps waiting for the client to write its message even after all bytes of the message have been written to the stream. This seems to be because the `ioutil.ReadAll` function is waiting for an `io.EOF` error as the signal to stop reading from the stream.

How can I tell Go that I am done writing to the TCP stream from Java? I can change both the Java TCP Client and Golang TCP Server codes, if that helps.

**NOTE:** The server was written like that because our Go TCP Client uses the below code:

```
func writeToConnection(connection *net.TCPConn, tcpCommand structs.TCPCommand) error {
    messageBytes, err := json.Marshal(tcpCommand)
    if err != nil {
        err = merry.Wrap(err)
        return err
    }

    _, err = connection.Write(messageBytes)
    if err != nil {
        err = merry.Wrap(err)
        return err
    }

    err = connection.CloseWrite()
    if err != nil {
        err = merry.Wrap(err)
        return err
    }

    return nil
}
```

Comment: Call [shutdownOutput](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#shutdownOutput()) to match the Go client.

Comment: @CeriseLimón Unfortunately, my client cannot close the socket after sending its message because it also needs to read a response from the server (only after reading the server message can I close the socket). I have updated my question to reflect this, thanks!

Comment: @CeriseLimón Never knew such a function existed. That might just work! :) Please add this as an answer so I can accept it if it works. Thanks!

Comment: @CeriseLimón It worked! Please add this as an answer so I can accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call [shutdownOputput](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#shutdownOutput()) to match the code in the Go client.